# Android json fetch issue WCF service

Tags: java, android, json, wcf, android-emulator

I have created a WCF service on localhost and it returns a json on invoke i want to get the json on android client but its not working somehow, i tried getting a json from a sample android tutorial site and that worked but my own localhost WCF service does not seem to work

```
package com.example.usa;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

public class Home extends Activity {
    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary/Service1/GetDataUsingDataContract";
                               //http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary/Service1/
    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";
     public static JSONObject json  ;

    JSONArray contacts = null;



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        final JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {



            @Override
            public void run() {

                Thread thread = new Thread()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        while(true) {
                            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                            // Creating JSON Parser instance
                            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                            // getting JSON string from URL
                            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

                            try {
                                // Getting Array of Contacts
                                contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                                // looping through All Contacts
                                for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
                                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                                    // Storing each json item in variable
                                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                                    String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                                    String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                                    // Phone number is agin JSON Object
                                    JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                                    String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                                    String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                                    String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);


                                    Log.w("ID",id);
                                    Log.w("Name",name);
                                    Log.w("Email",email);
                                    Log.w("Gender",gender);
                                    Log.w("mobile",mobile);
                                    Log.w("home",home);
                                    Log.w("office",office);
                                    Log.w("address",address);



                                    // creating new HashMap
                                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                                    map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                                    map.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                                    contactList.add(map);
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                        }
                    }
                };

                thread.start();




                //
                finish();
            }
        }, 0);





    }

}
```

this code throws this

```
10-04 13:31:30.402: D/dalvikvm(3043): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 15K, 4% free 4157K/4292K, paused 39ms, total 48ms
10-04 13:31:30.422: I/dalvikvm-heap(3043): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.637MB for 1536016-byte allocation
10-04 13:31:30.592: D/dalvikvm(3043): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 5656K/5796K, paused 160ms, total 160ms
10-04 13:31:32.562: W/System.err(3043): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:8732 refused
10-04 13:31:32.592: W/System.err(3043):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
10-04 13:31:32.592: W/System.err(3043):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-04 13:31:32.602: W/System.err(3043):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-04 13:31:32.602: W/System.err(3043):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
10-04 13:31:32.602: W/System.err(3043):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
10-04 13:31:32.602: W/System.err(3043):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
10-04 13:31:32.643: W/System.err(3043):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
10-04 13:31:32.643: W/System.err(3043):     at com.example.usa.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:38)
10-04 13:31:32.643: W/System.err(3043):     at com.example.usa.Home$1$1.run(Home.java:66)
10-04 13:31:32.643: W/System.err(3043): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 8732): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
10-04 13:31:32.682: W/System.err(3043):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
10-04 13:31:32.712: W/System.err(3043):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
10-04 13:31:32.712: W/System.err(3043):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
10-04 13:31:32.733: W/System.err(3043):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
10-04 13:31:32.733: W/System.err(3043):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
10-04 13:31:32.733: W/System.err(3043):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
10-04 13:31:32.742: W/System.err(3043):     ... 8 more
10-04 13:31:32.772: W/System.err(3043): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
10-04 13:31:32.812: W/System.err(3043):     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
10-04 13:31:32.812: W/System.err(3043):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
10-04 13:31:32.812: W/System.err(3043):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
10-04 13:31:32.812: W/System.err(3043):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
10-04 13:31:32.812: W/System.err(3043):     ... 13 more
10-04 13:31:32.854: E/Buffer Error(3043): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
10-04 13:31:32.917: E/JSON Parser(3043): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
10-04 13:31:32.917: W/dalvikvm(3043): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
10-04 13:31:32.917: E/AndroidRuntime(3043): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-96
10-04 13:31:32.917: E/AndroidRuntime(3043): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 13:31:32.917: E/AndroidRuntime(3043):     at com.example.usa.Home$1$1.run(Home.java:70)
10-04 13:31:35.052: I/Choreographer(3043): Skipped 1034 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-04 13:31:38.592: I/Choreographer(3043): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-04 13:36:33.602: I/Process(3043): Sending signal. PID: 3043 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Put you local host ip adresss complete.

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to connect to `localhost`, which means the android device itself. You are probably running your web service on a desktop within the same local network that you're testing on, so you will need to access the web service via the IP of your machine.

In windows, open up cmd.exe, run `ipconfig` and then find your IPv4 address, then replace `localhost` with that.

It should look something like, placing 192.168.1.2 with your IP:

```
private static String url = "http://192.168.1.2:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary/Service1/GetDataUsingDataContract";
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please mark the answer as correct if anybody else comes here with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

at first you have to deploy your service in your IIS an than you have to change the localhost to 10.0.2.2:Yourport